# Encoding Issue apending NSData to Post

Tags: objective-c, post, encoding, nsdata

I have got problem uploading a file to a server through POST

I build the request body by loading a html file and inserting the data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryMAsmIFCr12izlsoH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

%@
------WebKitFormBoundaryMAsmIFCr12izlsoH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="%@"
Content-Type: AES256/encrypted

%@
------WebKitFormBoundaryMAsmIFCr12izlsoH--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Datei absenden
------WebKitFormBoundaryMAsmIFCr12izlsoH--
```

But to insert the the data fia string with format, it must be a string. So I alloc initWithData:data encoding NSASCIIStringEncoding cause the data can not be displayed in UTF8. The rest of the request is in UTF8, so afterwards if need dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding. This breaks the data. There some bytes on the wrong place and so on. So I tried an other way, I spitted the html into two parts, and made a sandwich of it. html, data, html Unfortunately the request now looks like the second html is part of the file, so the file is broken again. 
Do you know a better method?
Thanks in advance,
Jannes

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to use `stringWithFormat` is fundamentally flawed. `NSString` is conceptually an array of Unicode data, but the data you are trying to put together may not be valid Unicode.

You'd be better off converting the various header portions to `NSData` instances and then concatenating those with the data you want to send.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The anser is: you need a linebreak between you data and the rest of the html. Like this: NSString* break = @"\n"; NSData* breakData = [break dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; [postbody appendData: fileData]; [postbody appendData: breakData];